# Change OpenLayers map style

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers

I am trying to create a map in OpenLayers. I have no problem with other APIs, but the map style is old. Also, there is another application named Snap (it's using OSM) that has a prettier style:

[image: Left image is Snap, Right image is my map]

How can I change OpenLayers map style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the layer being displayed or the map. Different API's provide different layers that might have multiple styles.

For example here:
https://cloud.maptiler.com/maps/